# java script to mark table rows upon variable

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

i am working on a project of Django, in which i show a table in the front page.
the table has a a "Changed" column which can be assign with "Read" or "Unread" only.
i want to add an option that if a row in a table has  "Unread" in the "changed" column that it will be highlighted.
my js so far:

```
{% block additional_js %}
<script>
   $( function() {
        var xeditable_options = {};
        var table = datatableview.initialize($('.datatable'),
                {
                    lengthMenu : [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1 ], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All" ] ],
                    fnRowCallback: datatableview.make_xeditable(xeditable_options),
                    bProcessing : true
                }
        );

       table.columnFilter( { sPlaceHolder : 'foot' } );

        table = table.api();
        table.page.len( 10 ).draw();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.
first needed to look for datatableview.js which is responsible to the table.
under "    make_xeditable: function(options)"
i have added :

```
        var html=String(mData[8]);
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = html;
        var a= (div.innerText);
        if (a=="Unread"){
            nRow.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
```

and it works. (also need to change the highlight coloring attributes in the css template so it wont run over the attempt to color the background)

Comment: table.dataTable tbody tr.selected {
  background-color: #b0bed9 !important; ---->  background-color: #b0bed9 (without the !important)